# ¿Cómo acceder a la propiedad de un objeto en un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, es2016

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo la clase `Player` donde hago su correspondiente constructor:

```
class Player{
constructor(name, description, team, voting){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.team = team;
    this.voting = voting;
}
```

Luego creo un array que relleno con instancias de la clase `Player`:

```
let arrayJugadores = [
new Player("Michael Jordan","Best Player","Chicago Bulls",5),
new Player("Kobe Bryant","3rd Most Pointer","Los Angeles Lakers",5),
new Player("Lebron James","The King","Cleveland Cavaliers",5),
new Player("Russel Westbrook","Dangerous","Oklahoma City Thunder",4),
new Player("Serge Ibaka","Spanish Black","Oklahoma City Thunder",1)
];
```

Y por último tengo mi función, que lo que se supone que debe hacer es comprobar si el valor del input `element` coincide con la propiedad `team` del objeto y devolver por consola todos los objetos que coincidan con esa propiedad:

```
function similar(){

let element = document.getElementById("equipo").value;

for (let i = 0; i <= arrayJugadores.length; i++){
    if(arrayJugadores[i].team === element){
        console.log(arrayJugadores[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando le paso el inspector de elementos para comprobar que todo se ejecuta correctamente, me devuelve lo siguiente:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of undefined`

¿Cómo se supone que puedo acceder a la propiedad del objeto del array para que haga la comprobación con el if?.

Muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier respuesta.

Comment: Estas accediendo correctamente al objeto del array , el error debe ser relacionado con la sintaxis o el scope , voy a intentar averiguar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en que has usado

`i <= arrayJugadores.length` (menor igual que)

cuando deberías usar

`i < arrayJugadores.length` (menor que).

A continuación un [stack snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65) con el cambio indicado

```js
class Player {
  constructor(name, description, team, voting) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.team = team;
    this.voting = voting;
  }
}


let arrayJugadores = [
  new Player("Michael Jordan", "Best Player", "Chicago Bulls", 5),
  new Player("Kobe Bryant", "3rd Most Pointer", "Los Angeles Lakers", 5),
  new Player("Lebron James", "The King", "Cleveland Cavaliers", 5),
  new Player("Russel Westbrook", "Dangerous", "Oklahoma City Thunder", 4),
  new Player("Serge Ibaka", "Spanish Black", "Oklahoma City Thunder", 1)
];


function similar() {

  let element = document.getElementById("equipo").value;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayJugadores.length; i++) {
    if (arrayJugadores[i].team === element) {
      console.log(arrayJugadores[i]);
    }
  }
}

similar()
```

```html
<input id="equipo" value="Chicago Bulls">
```

Comment: Efectivamente era por ese = . No me puedo creer que fuera un fallo tan tonto, de verdad muchísimas gracias por ésta ayuda, tienes todo mi agradecimiento.

Comment: @tazzmaniac el "agradecimiento" se expresa acepta la respuesta que ayudó  a resolver su problema. No está de más leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Te agradezco de nuevo la ayuda. No tenía ni idea de que había que aceptar las respuestas. Tomo nota para el futuro. Y por supuesto, aceptada está. Gracias de nuevo.